# на мобильном версии выдает ошибка 404 если убрать из ссылке /ru/ то заходит . На desctop работает все нормально

Tags: gatsbyjs

Здравствуйте добрый день.
У меня тут такое ситуация у меня гетсби интл не работает на мобилке выдаёт ошибку что (Эта страница не работает, поскольку { [www.adres.com](http://www.adres.com) } перенаправил вас слишком много раз. (-310)
Попробуйте это:

Очистите кэш и cookies (информация о вашем аккаунте может быть утеряна). )

на мобилке выдает ошибка 404 если убрать из ссылке /ru/ то заходит . В десктопе работает нормально

Comment: В вашем вопросе и есть ответ :) Очистите кэш

Comment: Не работает очистил кэш